# Getting java.lang.NullPointerException while calling activate method on TaskClient

Tags: drools, jbpm

Getting null pointer exception while starting calling the activate method on client object.Here is my code.

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/loanreq",method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public String loanRequest(HttpServletRequest req,HttpSession session) throws DroolsParserException, IOException, NamingException{

   StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = processEngine.getKsession();

   ksession.getWorkItemManager().registerWorkItemHandler("Human Task", new WSHumanTaskHandler());

   TaskClient client = new TaskClient(new MinaTaskClientConnector("UserTask",new MinaTaskClientHandler(SystemEventListenerFactory.getSystemEventListener())));

        client.connect("ipaddress", 9123);
        BlockingTaskOperationResponseHandler responseHandler =

                new BlockingTaskOperationResponseHandler();
        client.activate(3, "krisv", responseHandler);

        client.start(3, "krisv", responseHandler);

            client.complete( 3, "krisv", null, responseHandler );




   Map<String,Object> params=new HashMap();
   params.put("employee", "krisv");


   ProcessInstance processInstance =ksession.startProcess("com.vr.controller2",params); 


   System.out.println("id is "+processInstance.getId());

   return "return1";
  }
```

And i am getting the following exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jbpm.task.service.mina.MinaTaskClientConnector.write(MinaTaskClientConnector.java:118)
at org.jbpm.task.service.TaskClient.activate(TaskClient.java:651)
at com.vr.controller.hellocontroller.loanRequest(hellocontroller.java:181)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have seen the client object while debugging but it is not null.Dont Know why i am getting this error.I am getting this error at the line "client.activate()" not at "client.connect()".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I dont have problem as in  so said link.This is different case.It is establishing client connection and starting.Here i am not getting exception at client.connect() but at client.start()(something related to jbpm).

Comment: @smith the problem here is that `client.connect()` don't throw exceptions in any cases, it just return `true` or `false` to indicate that it's connected or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to stack trace this error appears because `session` inside `MinaTaskClientConnector` is `null`. As far as I understand from source code of [TaskClient](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jbpm/jbpm-human-task-core/5.3.0.Final/org/jbpm/task/service/TaskClient.java) and [MinaTaskClientConnector](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jbpm/jbpm-human-task-mina/5.4.0.Final/org/jbpm/task/service/mina/MinaTaskClientConnector.java#MinaTaskClientConnector.write%28java.lang.Object%29) this occurs because of failure in `connect` method, inside this block of code:

```
 try {
      connector.getFilterChain().addLast("codec",new ProtocolCodecFilter(new ObjectSerializationCodecFactory()));

      ConnectFuture future1 = connector.connect( address );
      future1.awaitUninterruptibly();
      if (!future1.isConnected()) {
          return false;
      }
      session = future1.getSession();
      return true;
 } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
      return false;
 }
```

You can find exact error in log or by putting breakpoint inside `catch` block.

Also I would advise check result of connect method (it returns `boolean` value to indicate about connection success) and do something like this:

```
if (client.connect("ipaddress", 9123) {
      BlockingTaskOperationResponseHandler responseHandler = new BlockingTaskOperationResponseHandler();
      client.activate(3, "krisv", responseHandler);
      client.start(3, "krisv", responseHandler);
      client.complete( 3, "krisv", null, responseHandler );
      Map<String,Object> params=new HashMap();
      params.put("employee", "krisv");
      ProcessInstance processInstance =ksession.startProcess("com.vr.controller2",params); 
      System.out.println("id is "+processInstance.getId());
      return "return1";
} else {
      //TODO code to report connection error
}
```

Comment: While i am using this connector.connect() it is showing as nosuchmethod.Is that connector MinaTaskClientConnector.

Comment: @smith `MinaTaskClientConnector.connect` will be called inside `TaskClient.connect` you just need to achieve that this method return `true` not `false`.

Comment: here there is no method called getfilterchain() inside this MinaTaskClientConnector

Comment: @smith `getfilterchain()` is method of 'connector' field of type `SocketConnector`  inside `MinaTaskClientConnector` this code part that I've inserted first is inside 'MinaTaskClientConnector' method 'connect' here: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jbpm/jbpm-human-task-mina/5.4.0.Final/org/jbpm/task/service/mina/MinaTaskClientConnector.java#MinaTaskClientConnector.connect%28org.apache.mina.transport.socket.SocketConnector%2Cjava.net.SocketAddress%29

Comment: HI tretyak can you give me your mail id so that i can communicate with you in future.